# How to enable app rating in android app if app is still not uploaded in playstore?

Tags: android

How can I add an option in my android app for people to rate it? I still not uploaded it and I want the app to redirect to the play store link after I upload it. is it possible or will I have to provide it in a later update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play Store links are based on your Package Id. Which should represent your company and product/project. So if you have company XYZ and product ABC you might want to use `com.xyz.abc.android` for your Package Id (which is also reffered to as Application Id).

Hence the URL would be:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xyz.abc.android`

Read more about [Set the Application ID here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)

Answer (score 0):

The URL always follow the same format. Just use:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**your.package.name**